# Find a uniquely defined element in this $\aleph_1$-indexed Cartesian product

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Denote by $A$ the set of all ordinals with cardinality exactly equal to ${\aleph}_0$, 
and for $\alpha\in A$ let $B_{\alpha}$ denote the set of all bijections
between $\alpha$ and $\omega$ ; finally let $B=\prod_{\alpha\in A}B_{\alpha}$.
Then $B$ is a Cartesian product of nonempty sets, and is therefore
nonempty.  The natural way to "exhibit" a $b\in B$ involves making many (${\aleph}_1$, 
in fact) arbitrary choices and is therefore highly non-contructive. Is there a definable $b\in B$ ? In other words, is there a formula $\phi$ of set theory such that ZFC proves that $\exists!  z, \phi(z)\wedge z\in B$ ?

My guess would be that "the $<_{L}$-smallest element of $L\cap B$" works, but I'm not sure. And I'd appreciate more elementary constructions.

Comment: One immediate hint, perhaps, is that in most cases canonical definable objects tend to find their ways into models of $\sf ZF$ as well. But we know that in $\sf ZF$ it is possible that there is no such choice of bijections (it would define an injective function from $\omega_1$ into $\mathcal P(\omega)$, but we know that it is consistent there is no such injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing. Of course in $L$, or even in other relatively tame models, you could prove there is such uniquely defined object.

But in general, this is not the case. Force with $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\omega_1)$ to make the old $\aleph_1$ countable. This forcing is homogeneous, therefore its weakest element decides the truth value of any statement about the ground model. In particular "What is the value of the canonical enumeration of $\omega_1^V$ at the point $n$" for any $n$. But this is of course impossible, since that would allow us to define a bijection from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$ in $V$.

(Or, in shorter words, if such $\phi$ and $z$ exist, then $z$ is certainly ordinal definable; and homogeneous forcings which are in $HOD$ do not change $HOD$. So by making new ordinals countable, but not adding objects to $HOD$, it is impossible to have such $\phi$ and $z$.)

Comment: A few days back I wondered how miserably choice could fail. Is it true that we can have an inner model $M$, where every set $x \in M \setminus (HOD)^M$ cannot be linear ordered? (This is the wrong place to ask such a question, but I'm only looking for a "yes"/"no"/"don't know" kind of answer here.) Oh and to state the obvious: I'm only considering cases where $(HOD)^M \neq M$.

Comment: Trivially no. Since there are singletons there... :)

Comment: Also, I got your email. Did you get my reply?

Comment: Grrr... This is exactly why I didn't post a question, yet. I'm just not sure how to ask this question in a meaningful way...

Comment: Let me know when you have something solid to ask. :-)

Comment: Here might be the question you might be after. $M$ such that for all $x\in M\setminus HOD^M$, $HOD(\{x\})\models\lnot\sf AC$. Something like this (maybe $L$ instead of $HOD$)? That if a set is not ordinal definable, then the model it generates is not a model of choice. The answer is again negative because you still have sets of ordinals outside of $HOD$.